# Why automatic type inference from the initialization list doesn't work in the constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17, type-deduction

Why can't I create an instance of a class initialized with an initialization list in the constructor of another class without explicitly specifying the type?

```
#include <map>
#include <optional>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> m1({{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}});
    std::map<std::string, int> m2{{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}};
    auto m3 = std::map<std::string, int>({{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}});

    using map_type = std::pair<const std::string, int>;
    std::optional<std::map<std::string, int>>omt1(std::in_place ,{map_type{"test1", 1}, map_type{"test2", 2}, map_type{"test3", 3}});
    std::optional<std::map<std::string, int>>omt2{std::in_place ,{map_type{"test1", 1}, map_type{"test2", 2}, map_type{"test3", 3}}};
    auto omt3 = std::optional<std::map<std::string, int>>(std::in_place ,{map_type{"test1", 1}, map_type{"test2", 2}, map_type{"test3", 3}});


    std::optional<std::map<std::string, int>>om1(std::in_place ,{{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}});
    std::optional<std::map<std::string, int>>om2{std::in_place ,{{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}}};
    auto om3 = std::optional<std::map<std::string, int>>(std::in_place ,{{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}});

    return 0;
}
```

compiller error:

```
main.cpp:18:107: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::optional, int> >::optional(const std::in_place_t&, )’
   18 |     std::optional<std::map<std::string, int>>om1(std::in_place ,{{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}});
      |                                                                                                           ^
```

Comment: You are using a templated constructor `std::optional`, that accepts any types as parameters. The compiler can't determine those types from the *brace-init* lists. You expect the compiler to look inside the implementation of `optional` constructor, figure out that those parameters are passed along to `std::map`, and then deduce based on `map`'s constructors - the compiler doesn't do that. Template parameter deduction is based on the function's declaration, not what's inside the body.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik In that case, what is the most concise way to initialize an object with an initialization list from literals in another object's constructor?

Comment: why without specifying the type? Whats wrong with the working alternatives?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Explicitly specifying the type is cumbersome if the list is large

Comment: You should be able to do something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/b9jrYh68f). You decide to what extent it's an improvement

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the (C++17) *deduction guides* for `std::optional` as follows:

```
std::optional o(
  std::map<std::string, int>{{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}}
);
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/rfK3WxYqT

The type of the map is written only once, and there is no need for your `map_type`.

---

**UPDATE**

As already mentioned, the problem with your definition:

```
std::optional<std::map<std::string, int>> om1(
  std::in_place ,{{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}}
);
```

is that a compiler is not able to deduce the template argument for `std::initializer_list`. A simple demo of this problem:

```
template <typename T>
void f(std::initializer_list<T>) { }

int main()
{
  f({1, 2, 3});  // OK; T deduced as int
  f({{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}); // ERROR
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/KofYjdz6v

Comment: Is it a constructor call from the object, not from the object's initialization list? Is creating an object together with another object intended to reduce copying overhead? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @Maxim There should be no copying. The temporary `map` used as an argument of `optional`'s constructor is _rvalue_. Consequently, the value is initialized by the move constructor. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/7drc4b9qd.

Comment: @Maxim But you can also write `std::optional o(std::move(m1));` together with your definition of `m1`. It will also move into the `optional`'s value.

Comment: Does this mean that a constructor with an initialization list of another object is useless?

Comment: I meant constructor number 7 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional

Comment: @Maxim But this constructor can be used. You used it for initialization of `omt1`, `omt2`, and `omt3`. The problem is of a different kind, as was already mentioned in comments. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

The Problem:
In the line that's causing the error:

```
std::optional<std::map<std::string, int>>om1(std::in_place ,{{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}});
```

You're using direct initialization, and the compiler is having trouble deducing the type of `{{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}}`. It's ambiguous whether this is an initializer list of pairs or something else.

The Solution:

Use list initialization (i.e., curly braces) for the **std::optional**

```
std::optional<std::map<std::string, int>> om1{std::in_place, {{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}}};
```

Comment: Your suggestion is `om2` which fails to compile too.